# Change configuration setting based on URL in Flask

Tags: python-2.7, flask

I am new to Flask, i have three sections in config.py file

say

`class Config(object):
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False
    DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite://:memory:'
class ProductionConfig(Config):
    DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://user@localhost/foo'
class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = True
class TestingConfig(Config):
    TESTING = True`

And as per [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/#configuring-from-files) we can pass one the config at a time and run the app so the app will run for the passed config settings only.

I am looking changing the config based on url pattern,

so say if url is:

http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/app/hello  should use

```
app.config.from_object(ProductionConfig)
```

http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/app_dev/hello  should use

```
app.config.from_object(DevelopmentConfig)
```

http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/app_test/hello  should use

```
app.config.from_object(TestingConfig)
```

Is it possible while running app i want to change config based on url pattern so that i dont have to run multiple instance of app at time.
Please guide me how can i catch the url pattern in middleware to change configuration file.

Comment: I would advise against doing this. I see this as adding some unnecessary complexity to your application and some other bad things. Your app will be doing some very different things when testing vs running production. Simple is better than complex.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you might be looking for is [application dispatching](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/appdispatch/), where each app is the same except for the configuration file that is loaded.

[here](https://github.com/saltycrane/flask-subdomaindevserver) is a solution for a very similar issue, except it uses subdomain dispatching rather than URL dispatching as you have requested.

The basic concept should apply, and taking this together with the examples in the first link should give you a good start for developing code that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this inside a route endpoint

```
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
```

but it affects the whole app object. So when you GET /api/app_dev/hello  and then /api/app/whatever; you are still using app_dev config.

Answer (score 0):

In config file you can set API
_PATH. and in blueprint you need to set this parameter for required APIs